# Triage Help : Could a link to meta answer be added in the UI?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

Like many, I've had (still having??) difficulties understanding the subtilities of Triage choices. Searching in Meta, I came on this very helpful wiki https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/4462333

It would have help me (and possible others) to see a link to it right from the start in the UI. Or have a link to an Help page with a similar content.

Would one of these be possible ?

[image]

Comment: The current help text should be replaced with that answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree. Any idea on how to suggest it ?

Comment: Well, this would be the way to suggest it. I'm sorry that it hasn't gotten much attention.